# How the malus law will be changed for the averaged intensity

Tags: optics

If a polarized beam of light passes through an polarizer then, the intensity of the  output  polarized light obey Malus law.

$$I =I_0 \cos^2 \phi$$

Now if we rotate the the polarizer with an angular frequency $\omega$ then how the malus law will be changed for the averaged intensity?

Comment: I think it should be $I=\frac{I_0}{\sqrt{2}} \cos^2 (\omega t + \phi)$

Comment: Somewhere I found that the average  output intensity  is $ I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} I_0 $ but can not recall that right now

Comment: Oh yes. You have that $\sqrt{2}$ part if you are talking of averaged output intensity. Editing my comment.

Comment: Actually you can calculate the average output intensity by integrating the net output intensity over one time period divided by the time period. Thats how you get the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ part.